# Best way to use a lookup value in SQL view?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to lookup a date from a table and then filter another table using the value. These two tables are not related in any way.

Here is the dummy example setup

```
CREATE TABLE config (
    idp INT NOT NULL,
    eff_date DATE NOT NULL , 
    last_transaction DATE NOT NULL, 
    a VARCHAR(50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO config (idp, eff_date, last_transaction, a)
  VALUES
(1, DATE '2021-05-03', DATE '2021-05-02', 'abc')
;

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    mth_eff_date DATE NOT NULL , 
    amt INT NOT NULL 
);
CREATE INDEX transaction_date ON transactions (mth_eff_date);

INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-02', 825);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-02', 650);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-02', 825);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-03', 500);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-03', 650);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-04', 235);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (DATE '2021-05-06', 853);
```

Here is my solution which has really bad performance on large datasets. Whilst testing I checked the running times if I hardcode the **`(SELECT last_transaction from lt)`** part and it runs really quick.

```
WITH lt AS 
  (SELECT last_transaction
    FROM config
  ),
  transactions_filt AS 
  (SELECT * 
    FROM transactions
    WHERE mth_eff_date <= (SELECT last_transaction FROM lt)
  )
  SELECT * FROM transactions_filt
;
```

(The above is available as a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7d5a7/1/0).)

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A bit of a guess, but if you did `select max(last_transaction) from lt` you might fool the optimiser into a plan that uses a one-off value rather than a table value.  That  might help, as might removing the lt CTE

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` is a MySQL function, not an Oracle database function. Please tag your question correctly, as proper syntax and expected optimizer behavior for your query could be different.

Comment: @LoztInSpace nah that doesnt work unfortunately

Comment: Please post the query plan. Is there an index on `test.config.last_transaction`? is there an index on `test.transactions.mth_eff_date`?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid there is an index on transactions, there isnt in config. The tables are not related via a key

Comment: `'%d/%m/%Y'` isn't a valid date format in Oracle. Is it MySQL?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I came up with the example in MySQL - should be oracle. fixed it now

Comment: @wxecqz123 . . . The `insert` code is still not Oracle compatible, which makes the question confusing.

Comment: @wxecqz123: information relevant to the question (such as what indices are defined) should be edited into the question, rather than left in [comments](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Do the `WITH` clauses serve some purpose in the actual query? In the example, the aliased queries are too simple to warrant `WITH`. Does table `config` contain many rows? To echo Nick's comment, please post the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

When a query has poor performance, one of the first responses is to try indexing relevant columns, in this case `config.last_transaction`.

```
CREATE INDEX config_last_transaction ON config (last_transaction);
```

With the small sample set, the difference won't be noticeable in performance, but is visible in the execution plans. Without an index:

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 1 | 22 | 3 | 00:00:01 |
| 1 | TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TRANSACTIONS | 1 | 22 | 0 | 00:00:01 |
| * 2 | INDEX RANGE SCAN | TRANSACTION_DATE | 1 |  | 0 | 00:00:01 |
| 3 | TABLE ACCESS FULL | CONFIG | 1 | 9 | 3 | 00:00:01 |

With an index:

| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT |  | 1 | 22 | 1 | 00:00:01 |
| 1 | TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TRANSACTIONS | 1 | 22 | 0 | 00:00:01 |
| * 2 | INDEX RANGE SCAN | TRANSACTION_DATE | 1 |  | 0 | 00:00:01 |
| 3 | INDEX FULL SCAN | CONFIG_LAST_TRANSACTION | 1 | 9 | 1 | 00:00:01 |

Note the query went from using a table scan with cost "3" to an index scan with cost "1".

Another approach (not exclusive of creating an index) is to try alternate ways of writing the query, such as a join:

```
SELECT t.mth_eff_date, t.amt
  FROM transactions t
    INNER JOIN config c ON t.mth_eff_date <= c.last_transaction
;
```